# Montando ranking com critério de desempate com array

Tags: php, javascript, json, array, funções

Estou precisando ordenar esse Array inicialmente pelos pontos e caso ocorra empate, aqueles índices do array que empataram seria desempatado no games, se continuasse empatado pularia para o tiebreak e se continuasse iria para idade.

O que consegui até o momento é ordenar pelos pontos e identificar os índices que estão com os pontos empatados.

Se alguem souber uma forma mais fácil de desenvolver esse tipo de ranking, fico muito grato.

```
    const obj = [
    {nome: "Elinete",   apelido: "elinete",     pontos: "99",   games:"200",    tiebreak:"4",   idade:"30"},
    {nome: "Luna",      apelido: "lunajessica", pontos: "82",   games:"180",    tiebreak:"9",   idade:"35"},
    {nome: "Thamires",  apelido: "tata",        pontos: "50",   games:"130",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"40"},
    {nome: "Alex",      apelido: "alex",        pontos: "50",   games:"150",    tiebreak:"-1",  idade:"45"},
    {nome: "Hugo",      apelido: "hugobornio",  pontos: "50",   games:"181",    tiebreak:"10",  idade:"19"},
    {nome: "Aparecido", apelido: "aparecido",   pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "Jaime",     apelido: "jaime",       pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "André",     apelido: "andré",       pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "João",      apelido: "joão",        pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "moacir",    apelido: "moacir",      pontos: "10",   games:"100",    tiebreak:"2",   idade:"21"}

    ]

    obj.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.pontos.localeCompare(a.pontos);
    });

    const indexPontosIguais = []

    function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {


    if(index > 0){

        const pontosAnterior = obj[index-1].pontos
        const pontosAtual = element.pontos

            if(pontosAtual == pontosAnterior){

                const indexAtual = index
                const indexAnterior = index-1

                indexPontosIguais.push(indexAnterior, indexAtual)

            }
         }
     }

     obj.forEach(logArrayElements);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a função `sort` é mais prática para isso.
Basicamente ela faz `foreach` em todos os elementos, passando dois a dois para se comparar, onde devemos:

- retornar -1 se o primeiro é menor
- retornar 1 se o segundo é menor
- retorna 0 se ambos são iguais

Dai é possível fazer uma function para validar pontos e games:

```js
const obj = [
    {nome: "Elinete",   apelido: "elinete",     pontos: "99",   games:"200",    tiebreak:"4",   idade:"30"},
    {nome: "Luna",      apelido: "lunajessica", pontos: "82",   games:"180",    tiebreak:"9",   idade:"35"},
    {nome: "Thamires",  apelido: "tata",        pontos: "50",   games:"130",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"40"},
    {nome: "Alex",      apelido: "alex",        pontos: "50",   games:"150",    tiebreak:"-1",  idade:"45"},
    {nome: "Hugo",      apelido: "hugobornio",  pontos: "50",   games:"181",    tiebreak:"10",  idade:"19"},
    {nome: "Aparecido", apelido: "aparecido",   pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "Jaime",     apelido: "jaime",       pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "André",     apelido: "andré",       pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "João",      apelido: "joão",        pontos: "30",   games:"120",    tiebreak:"3",   idade:"18"},
    {nome: "moacir",    apelido: "moacir",      pontos: "10",   games:"100",    tiebreak:"2",   idade:"21"}

    ]

const sortFunc = (a, b) => {
  // verica se pontos são iguais, para desempatar por games
  if (a.pontos == b.pontos) {
   // retorna:
   // -1 se a < b, 1 se a > b, 0 se a = b
     return a.games < b.games
       ? -1
       : a.games > b.games
         ? 1
         : 0;
  }
  
  // mesma lógica do anterior
   return a.pontos < b.pontos
       ? -1
       : a.pontos > b.pontos
         ? 1
         : 0;
  
}

var sorted = obj.sort(sortFunc);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Muito bom, me ajudou muito obrigado.

Comment: não esqueça de aceitar a resposta se ela ajudou a resolver ;)